# Javascript exec() - a generic function that exec's and returns stdout, stderr

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm super new to JS and am struggling with a very basic task as I familiarize myself with it. I want to create a simple run(cmd) function that would receive a string with a command, and return an object containing stderr and stdout.

From what I found, I need to use exec or spawn, but I'm having trouble turning the examples online into a returning function:

```js
const { exec } = require("child_process");

let run(cmd) = exec(cmd, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    ret = {
        out: "",
        err: "",
        msg: ""
    }
    if (error) {
        ret.msg = error.message;
    }
    if (stderr) {
        ret.err = stderr;
    }
    ret.out = stdout;
    return ret;
});


out = run("ls -al");
console.log(out);
```

This doesn't work and I'm probably making mistakes on multiple levels here

UPDATE: The snippet I posted doesn't work, no outputs, just errors. I posted it because it is very simple and straightforward in terms of showing what I want to achieve. If I need to drop exec() for something else - I'm happy to hear suggestions.

Comment: what does this `console.log` display?

Comment: Your syntax for defining `run` as a function doesn't look correct.

Comment: should probably be `let run = (cmd) => (exec....)`

Comment: returning exec also wouldn't work, `run` won't be able to return anything meaningful without making it return a promise or making exec sync (sync should generally be avoided). Having run instead accept a callback would be the most straight-forward way to get this "working"

Comment: I don't know unfortunately what does exec do but usually when you wanna call function within a function it is something like this https://jsfiddle.net/1vz365sh/
 now depending on how exec works you might need a promise

Comment: as I read that is a callback which is called after the script execution so depending on how you wanna use it it can be easier or harder so if you could specify how you wanna use the output then we could propose the best solution

Comment: If you're really super new to js and have not yet heard of asynchronous functions, `exec` maybe isn't a good example. Try to use [`execSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processexecsynccommand-options) instead, or learn about asynchronous callbacks and promises first.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi I know how async stuff works, just not in JS (yet). My aim is to make a simple script, with focus on simplicity and readability, not performance and multithreading, so I'll stick to `Sync` stuff for now whenever possible

Comment: @dyasny You can get very high readability with `aysnc`/`await` as well. Especially as you will encounter cases where there is no synchronous counterpart, you'll probably have to write asynchronous code anyway, so you better use it everywhere - for consistency and simplicity.

Comment: This might also help with better understanding callbacks: https://felix-kling.de/blog/2019/javascript-callbacks-misconceptions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

exec() is a callback-based function and there is no way to do what you are doing without promisifying exec() or using a callback. You are returning from a function of it's own.

This is not even correct syntax for a function. You probably want to do something like this:

```js
let run = (cmd, callback) => {
    exec(cmd, (e, so, se) => {
      // do stuff with the e, so, and se
      callback(e, so, se);
    });
};

run('ls', (e, so, se) => {
  // at this point you might just as well use exec()
});
```

Comment: I'm happy to replace exec() with something else that makes more sense for my specific use case. 

Basically I'm trying to use JS as a scripting and automation language instead of my customary python, simply because the current set of existing docker images already has node and js in place and bringing in python as well would bloat the images.

Comment: @dynasny Is there a reason you can't use promises or callbacks?

Comment: No reason, I'm just aiming for "as simple as possible", and making things async in my experience tends to lead away from that. Performance isn't important here, just simplicity and quick implementation

Comment: @dyasny Try `execSync`.